# Is there an analog of PhotoShop's "Magic Wand Tool" in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, select, pixel

I want to interactively select rasters pixels based on it's values and modify them.

Here is example of what this "Magic Wand Tool" should do:

[image]

Comment: What precisely does this analog to the "Magic Wand Tool" need to do?

Comment: It could be used for interactive classifications. For example I click on the river - then selection extended to all the river and then I change all selected pixels to class 1.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll get a tool that does *exactly* what you've described...
Something similar, but maybe not as diverse in its use, could be the **Grid Editor** from a Dutch company called ARIS. http://www.aris.nl --> GridEditor

[image: grideditor]

It's able to easily change the raster values of selected cells. Also, it's able to do this (quote from website):

> - change the value/color of a zone of cells with identical values (paintcan)
> - replace one value with another value in the entire grid (value replacer)

So I guess this is pretty close to what you try to find. Now to the downside of the tool: I've only ever tried the free trial version, which is quite limited in use. For the full version you need to pay. Licenses are permanent but they cost like 390 $...

Answer (score 1):

[TerraAmazon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n--T45jWXPE) offers a magic wand tool. Unfortunately it requires that you setup a postgis server first.

Answer (score 1):

The [ArcScan extension](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/what-is-arcscan-.htm) docs talk about a tool named **[Magic Erase](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/using-the-raster-painting-erase-tools.htm)** which sounds like it is more interactive than Photoshop's magic wand but still useful:

> - Click an erase tool on the Raster Painting toolbar. [...] You can change the brush size with the Erase Size button Erase Size.
> - Click the Magic Erase tool Magic Erase. [...] Drag the tool over the raster cells to erase them. When using the Magic Erase tool, connected
>   cells are erased, although any connected cells that extended beyond
>   the dragged box are not erased.

Also perhaps of interest is the QGIS [Magic Wand](https://github.com/Kanahiro/MagicWand) plugin by @Kanahiro. It creates a polygon by analysing the map canvas. There are settings for threshold and accuracy, and they suggest adjusting saturation for better results.